# how can we make ListHeaderComponent as sticky header in SectionList?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

### Description

i am using horizontal tab bar inside `ListHeaderComponent` and I want make `ListHeaderComponent` as a sticky header in SectionList. we can make stickyheader in flatlist by `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` but it does not work in **SectionList**

### React Native version:

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      CPU: (12) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8850H CPU @ 2.60GHz
      Memory: 38.35 MB / 16.00 GB
      Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
    Binaries:
      Node: 12.15.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.21.1 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.13.4 - /usr/local/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      iOS SDK:
        Platforms: iOS 12.4, macOS 10.14, tvOS 12.4, watchOS 5.3
      Android SDK:
        API Levels: 28, 29
        Build Tools: 28.0.3, 29.0.1, 29.0.2
        System Images: android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5791312
      Xcode: 10.3/10G8 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
      react-native: 0.59.8 => 0.59.8
    npmGlobalPackages:
      rename-horizon: 1.1.0
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

### Steps To Reproduce

Provide a detailed list of steps that reproduce the issue.

1. make section list  and add `ListHeaderComponent` props
2. add `stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}` in section list
   it will not make `ListHeaderComponent` as sticky header

### Expected Results

it should be making `ListHeaderComponent` as a sticky header. or alternative way to make it sticky header

[image: foodpanda]

Comment: Hey Muhammad, I am dealing with the same problem as you. Looks like `SectionList` lacks the `stickyHeaderIndices` prop that is available in the `FlatList` component. Did you found any way to make it work?

Comment: Hey @Numan, Did you manage to resolve the issue ?

Comment: have you found out how to fix this?

Comment: @BryanLumbantobing not yet, i fixed it by using scrollview. https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/29547

Comment: i ended up extracting the header from `ListHeaderComponent` and render the header outside `SectionList` instead

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this.

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  {renderStickyListHeaderComponent()}
  <SectionList
    {...sectionListprops}
    ref={sectionListRef}     
    sections={sectionData}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}   
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 2):

To make the top or any other header sticky for section list, provide a custom scroll component:

```
const CustomScrollComponent = (props) => <ScrollView {...props} stickyHeaderHiddenOnScroll={true} stickyHeaderIndices={[0]} />
```

then in your section list:

```
<SectionList   
  // other props
  renderScrollComponent={CustomScrollComponent}
/>
```

Answer (score -4):

you can use renderSectionHeader & stickySectionHeadersEnabled = true

```
render() {
  return (
    <SectionList
      data={sections}
      renderSectionHeader = {({section:{title}}) => (<YourHeader>)}
      stickySectionHeadersEnabled/>
 )
}
```